# passportJS, req.isAuthenticated() is always one step behind on login and signup

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, ejs

I am currently experiencing an issue with passportJS. I am using a template to render the pages (EJS). The login and signup is always one step behind as I am having a different navigation bar when the user is logged in. Once I hit the submit button with the correct credentials on the login page, it does not update the navbar the user being redirected. I need to either refresh the page or click on another link within the app.

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password"
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
      knex
        .select("*")
        .from("users")
        .where({ email })
        .first()
        .then(user => {
          if (!user) return done(null, false);
          const hash = user.password;
          bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
            if (res === true) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false);
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return done(err);
        });
    }
  )
);

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate(
  'local'), function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user.id) {
      res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
      console.log("===========> working", res.locals.isAuthenticated)
      res.locals.user = req.user;
      console.log("===========> working", res.locals.user)
      res.redirect('/')
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login')
    }
  }
);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  console.log(res.locals.isAuthenticated, res.locals.user)
  next();
});
```

Above is the code I have with local strategy. The two console.logs with "======> working" show "true" and the user object with the right credentials and does the proper redirect.

However the second function shows "false", undefined until I refresh.

Any thoughts about where the problem could be? Many thanks!

Comment: The `passport.authenticate` will issue the cookie. The cookie, when issued, is in the response only. For the cookie to be in the request, a roundtrip has to be made. Your second function runs unconditionally, as a middleware. This means it will notice the cookie only in the very next request. This is expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer! I am trying to understand what is happening since I don't have much experience and quite new to web development. What do you mean by roundtrip? Should I send another get request on a condition like `if (req.session && !req.isAuthenticated()) { app.get(), etc ....}` ? I am also quite confused, because for some reason on Safari, everything works fine! I console.logged `req.isAuthenticated()`, and I get `false`, then  `POST /login` and then `true`. Could it be something related to Chrome?? or is Safari doing the additional request to the server for me? Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `console.log(req.isAuthenticated())` is in the second middle function:
`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});`
In addition, I tested it on Firefox and it does work as well :-/ (no additional refresh necessary)

Comment: A *roundtrip* is yet another request from a browser after your server returns a response. Nonetheless, you definitely need an http debugger (burp, fiddler) and see requests/responses and when the cookie is appended and when it's there in the request.